# Getting error when trying to build a column with an IF statement

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to have a column that is able to be change if the column/s that it is referencing from change.

I am making a manning cards which will indicated how well trained someone is.

For example:

```
 Type 'ABC'             Type 'ABC'               Type'ABC'             Type'ABC'             Type'ABC123'
'table1'[Employee]|| 'table1'[Training1]|| 'table1'[Training2] || 'table1'[Traning3]|| 'table1'[CompliantColor]
       Stan       ||         Yes        ||          Yes        ||        Yes        ||         Green
       Tom        ||         No         ||          Yes        ||        Yes        ||         Red
       Dick       ||         Yes        ||          No         ||        Yes        ||         Red
       Harry      ||         Yes        ||          Yes        ||         No        ||         Red
```

From this I want the ColpliantColor to change color to Red if the personal has not done one of the training's, or Green if they have completed all of the training's.

```
CompliantColor = IF('table1'[training1]="No"||'table1'[training2]="No"||'table1'[training3]="No","http://ThecolorRed","http://ThecolorGreen")
```

To do this I have tried to have the CompliantColor change through a picture that I am holding in a Web-server so hyper-referencing it. I would have expected this to have changed the CompliantColor to the http://ThecolorRed if any one of training coloumns = "No". 
Instead i Get the error: Cannot convert value 'Yes' of type Text to type Number.
This error occurs when I am trying to define my column.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the question title. What are the types of each of your columns, 'Table'[Training1], 'Table'[Training2], 'Table'[Training3]? When does the error come? Do you get it on model load/refresh? Do you get it when defining your measure/column? Do you get it when trying to put your measure on a visual? What is the thing you're trying to build here, a measure or a column? Please update your question with more detail so we can better help you.

Comment: Thank you for the advice greggyb I have amended my question and i hope this gives some more incites

Comment: Are you doing this in DAX or in Power Query? Please show a screenshot of where you are working. The type headers you've shared are what I'd expect to see in Power Query, but the code you posted is DAX.